# Unable to install package Subprocess Error: metadata-generation-failed

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install this python package with found [here](https://github.com/fubel/sparselandtools). with `pip install sparselandtools`

(sparse) C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi>pip install sparselandtools

```
Collecting sparselandtools
  Using cached sparselandtools-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.6
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting requests==2.23.0
  Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting urllib3==1.25.8
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting packaging==20.1
  Using cached packaging-20.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting py==1.8.1
  Using cached py-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83 kB)
Collecting imageio==2.8.0
  Using cached imageio-2.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting docutils==0.16
  Using cached docutils-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (548 kB)
Collecting pkginfo==1.5.0.1
  Using cached pkginfo-1.5.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting prettyplotlib==0.1.7
  Using cached prettyplotlib-0.1.7-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting atomicwrites==1.3.0
  Downloading atomicwrites-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.9 kB)
Collecting cycler==0.10.0
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting numba==0.48.0
  Using cached numba-0.48.0.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [44 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3024, in _dep_map
          return self.__dep_map
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2821, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3015, in _parsed_pkg_info
          return self._pkg_info
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2821, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: _pkg_info

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p1enksfd\numba_67193ed1a8b047c58e78712515ebcd63\setup.py", line 360, in <module>
          setup(**metadata)
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 154, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 148, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 826, in fetch_build_eggs
          resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
          new_requirements = dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1]
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2742, in requires
          dm = self._dep_map
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3026, in _dep_map
          self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3035, in _compute_dependencies
          for req in self._parsed_pkg_info.get_all('Requires-Dist') or []:
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3017, in _parsed_pkg_info
          metadata = self.get_metadata(self.PKG_INFO)
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1418, in get_metadata
          value = self._get(path)
        File "C:\Users\Manu Dwivedi\.conda\envs\tfgym\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1622, in _get
          with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
      FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\manu dwivedi\\.conda\\envs\\tfgym\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy-1.23.0.dist-info\\METADATA'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

The problem seems to be when collecting meta-data for numba, so I tried running the installation in another environment and it fails similarly even when run in a new environmentco. However, when the installation is run in `base` it seems to go just fine.

Another issue I see is when setup.py is run (unsuccessfully), it is referring to meta data from a different environment. Looking for a workaround.

Comment: Have you ever tried to create a new virtual environment and give it a shot?

Comment: @HoseinBasafa It doesn't seem to work in new environments either, this seems to be a very minor issue but I can't seem to pin point where it is going wrong since it does install just fine in base